# Is there an admin plugin for Python Pylon?

Tags: python, pylons

Im moving from django to pylons, is there an admin app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box, but there are few options you can use. See [Forms - Pylons Cookbook - PythonWeb](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Forms) for the options:

- [formalchemy](http://code.google.com/p/formalchemy/) - the only one I used personally, and there is even an extension module for pylons documented [formalchemy.ext.pylons  – Pylons extensions](http://docs.formalchemy.org/ext/pylons.html), which I recommend to try out.
- ToscaWidgets
- DBSprockets
- even Django's newforms (the link to it on the site above is broken, but google for it)